# Table align on a unordered list item

Tags: css, icefaces

I have this really tricky CSS formatting issue that i need a quick override fix to align the bullet point with the table I have as a list item. Don't ask me why we have a form like this, but we're using JSF for an internal tool that QA is complaining about. Regardless, there is a table that contains the dropdown box and those radio buttons you see inside a `<li></li>` block.

What can I apply to either the table, the li, or wrap it in something else to get the bullet point to be vertically centered with that table?

[image: Tricky unordered list formatting]

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have seemingly fixed the issue for IE, but not Chrome. We only are concerned with IE in the company, so I figured I'd post my solution.

I set the list item to have a `vertical-align: middle;` and the table to be `display:inline;`.

If anyone has a better solution, I'd like to hear it for the future. Thanks!